# How can I pass Tweepy live stream text to Flask App?

Tags: python, api, flask, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to create a live streaming Flask app using tweepy live streaming...but, the only way I've seen to send tweets data for my app was by writing/reading a file...is there any way to make it more efficiently?

Writing example:

```
def on_data(self, data):
    json_content = json.loads(data)
with open('tweets.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(json_content['text'])
```

Reading example:

```
with open('tweets.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = file.readline()
```

is there any way to make it a direct connection?